# Convert filename to URI in Rust

Tags: rust, path, uri

In Python, we have:

```py
pathlib.Path("~/hello/world").expanduser().as_uri()
# or
pathlib.Path("/hello/world").as_uri()
```

In C, we have:

```c
char* uri = g_filename_to_uri("/hello/world", NULL, NULL)
// ...
g_free(uri)
```

What is the Rust's equivalent?

Comment: Note that your C example is not standard C. Standard C has no concept of URI. Your example uses a particular library (glib). Similarly standard Rust has no concept of URI, so this would depend on what crate you use.

Comment: @Jmb I'm asking for a working solution. It **doesn't matter** if it is from a third party or first party. (The glib code is just an example of doing the given task in one way).

Comment: @Jmb Asking how to do a concrete task that cannot be accomplished using the standard library is certainly not off-topic for StackOverflow. If that were so, we would reject all questions that require scoped threads, or Rayon, tokio, regex, etc.

Comment: @Jmb I fail to read any "how to" in this question... that just a question that ask for a lib. there no description no link nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`from_file_path`](https://docs.rs/url/2.2.2/url/struct.Url.html#method.from_file_path) method from the `url` crate seems to provide the functionality you're after:

```
let url = Url::from_file_path("/hello/world").unwrap();
println!("{}", url);  // prints file:///hello/world
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cb73cdf7ae4ac94b5899f13675652139)